# Why does Tailwind declare CSS variables multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am working on a react project with the tailwind. I checked the inspection of Chrome and saw the same tailwinds variables multiple times. I thought maybe something is not working properly in our project and checked Shopify and it was the same, I wonder why it is working in this way?
Screenshots are taken from first page of Shopify[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Tailwind CSS default variables defined for `::backdrop` in a separate rule from the `*, ::before, ::after` rule for two reasons:

1. The `*, ::before, ::after` selector does not cover `::backdrop`. As per [tailwindlabs/tailwindcss#8526](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/8526):

   > This PR adds the `::backdrop` pseudo-element to our universal default rules, which fixes an issue where utilities like `backdrop:backdrop-blur` would not work because the variables that rule depended on were not defined.
2. As for why it is in a separate rule, it could be due to browser support. According to [MDN, the last major web browser to support `::backdrop` was Safari 15.4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::backdrop#browser_compatibility) which was released on March 14<sup>th</sup> 2022. The aforementioned pull request [tailwindlabs/tailwindcss#8526](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/8526) was [merged on June 6<sup>th</sup> 2022](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/8526#event-6755722544) and [released with `v3.1.0` on June 8<sup>th</sup> 2022](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#added-7).

   This means at that time, only very recent Safari browsers would have support for the `::backdrop` element. If `::backdrop` would be with the `*, ::before, ::after` rule selector as `*, ::before, ::after, ::backdrop`, this would break sites on older Safari browsers, since the `*, ::before, ::after, ::backdrop` rule would not apply since one of the components were not supported. This could be a major regression so they [separated out the `::backdrop` selector into its own rule in pull request #8567](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/8567) that was [released in `v3.1.1`](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#311---2022-06-09).